# Are visa and study permits considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, asking-questions

Would it be considered off topic if I ask questions about F1, J1 visas and study permits?

From my experience the travel stackexchange community frowns upon such questions.

Comment: I'd go for the expats route. Give those guys some traffic. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not off topic at all, but you could also ask at [expats.se](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).